# operator== in base and Equals in derived

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading, equality

I have a base class that is compared by reference, and a derived class that is compared by value (showing just the lines that are relevant here):

```
class Term : IReadOnlyList<Term>
    public static bool operator ==(Term a, Term b)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(a, null))
            return false;
        return a.Equals(b);
    }

sealed class CompoundTerm : Term, IReadOnlyList<Term>
    public override bool Equals(object o)
```

So the derived class overrides `Equals`, but the base class has to overload `==` because it is possible and indeed likely that `a == b` will occur in a context where `a` and `b` are declared as `Term` but actually point to `CompoundTerm`.

As far as I can tell - please correct me if I'm wrong - this is all necessary and correct.

The compiler unfortunately is not happy with it:

```
Term.cs(40,11): warning CS0660: 'Term' defines operator == or operator != but does not override Object.Equals(object o)
```

What's the best thing to do here? I could use the brute force solution of disabling the warning, but I'd like to check and make sure there isn't a more elegant solution, some idiom I'm missing.

Comment: "I have a base class that is compared by reference" - that's not what your base class does. It calls `Equals`, which can be overridden in the derived class. It sounds like you should potentially override `Equals` as an *abstract* method in the base class, to force all subclasses to provide an implementation. (Ditto GetHashCode.) (That's assuming you can make your `Term` class abstract as well, which seems likely.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure, I could make `Term` abstract and have `AtomicTerm` derived class be the one that is compared by reference. In that scenario, `AtomicTerm.Equals` is required, but can be a one-liner that just returns `ReferenceEquals(this, o)`?

Comment: @JonSkeet However, in that case, what do I do for `AtomicTerm.GetHashCode`? Is there a similarly handy way to call the default version that works by reference?

Comment: You can use `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(object)`, but it's pretty odd for just that *one* kind of term to have reference equality, but all others to have value equality... Also note that your operator can be simplified to call `Equals(a, b)`. That handles nullity.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a base class that is compared by reference, and a derived class
>   that is compared by value (showing just the lines that are relevant
>   here)

Your current implementation doesn't necessarily perform reference equality; it actaully calls potential overloads of `Equals`.

> So the derived class overrides Equals, but the base class has to overload == ...

I don't understand why, if the base class overrides `Equals`, you need to overload `==` in the base class. `==` already performs reference comparison if no overload is defined, because the static `== (object, object)` is resolved at compile time.

> ... it is possible and indeed likely that a == b will occur in a context where a and b are declared as Term but actually point to CompoundTerm.

What the real type of `a` and `b` are is irrelevant when calling the `==` operator. `==` is a static method and will therefore resolve based on the reference type of the arguments:

```
object aString = "Hello";
object theSameString = new string(new[] { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' }); //to avoid string interning
var referenceEquals = aString == theSameString; //false: object == object
var valueEquals = (string)aString == (string)theSameString; //true: string == string
```

Now what I understand you are trying is precisely to perform reference equality when calling `==` if `a` and `b` are `Term` and not a subclass and to otherwise perform potential value equality.

This seems rather confusing, to be honest. I'd recommend having `==` always perform reference equality (don't overload it) and if you need potential value equality use `Equals`and document the class or code to make this behavior clear.